# How to talk to superview's controller?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have `UIView` subclass that is being added to my View Controller's main view. It contains audio player controls and slides in when an audio item is being played.

I am already updating the view’s UI to reflect the playing state (elapsed duration, etc.) just fine.

What I'm wondering is how I should talk to the superview's VC when the controls are pressed or when the progress slider is scrubbed.

- Should I make the superview’s controller a delegate?
- Should the superview’s controller register as a KVO observer and expose some relevant properties in the view?
- Should I use the notification center and post notifications?

I imagine these are all valid, and this isn't a question on which is better, rather which one is appropriate for my situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use UIControl target–action, just as you would with *any* button, slider, or other control.

Answer (score 0):

KVO does not fit because how would you observe a button press? By setting a `wasPressed`? And then unsetting it? Which will cause another trigger, between those you would have to distinguish!? It would just get messy.

I personally don´t like notifications for this kind of communication because they just cause a useless overhead. And beyond that I don´t like to base my code's functionality on strings and comparison of those strings. You would have to create them somewhere globally or have them written in multiple spaces etc. - nope. *And* you will no longer have a predictable program flow.

I would go with **delegation**! It is clean. You can specify and see who calls what and with what parameters rather than some random objects in notifications.

*Beyond that: your question will probably get closed because it is primarily opinion-based.*

Comment: I specifically avoided asking an opinion-based question. Even your answer goes to show that since you think delegation is the only appropriate answer. I appreciate your input.